# How to send ajax request in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, capybara

I am sending ajax request in javascript homepage.js file

```
function GotoHomePage() {
var URL = 'homepage/1';
$.ajax({
    url : URL,
    success : function() {
    },
    error:function(){
    }
});
}
```

Controller code products_controller.rb file:

```
def homepage
@val="here is query"
end
```

Routes routes.rb file:

```
match "homepage/1" => 'products#homepage'
```

Rspec products_controller_spec.rb file:

```
describe ProductDetailsController do
 render_views
   describe '#homepage' do
   before { xhr :get, 'homepage/1' }
   it { response.status.should == 200 }
   end
 end
```

But i am getting error

```
before { xhr :get, 'homepage/1' }
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:controller=>"products", :action=>"homepage/1"}
```

Comment: Why is your URL variable (in your JS) `homepage01/1` - that is, why is the `01` in there?

Comment: @MrDanA, nevertheless he's getting error while running spec

Comment: @ted I don't mean that of the hardcoded `1` vs the use of `:id` in the routes. Isn't the base of the URI still wrong? `homepage` instead of `homepage01`?

Comment: @user2244199, just to be sure, you want to get `http://localhost:3000/homepage/1` route, right?

Comment: @MrDanA, yup you're 100% right. I've just meant that this js method is not the one that raises exception

Comment: @ted Ah yes sorry I didn't mean to imply that was at the heart of the error. Just wanted the asker to note that!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the route from

```
match "homepage/1" => 'products#homepage'
```

to

```
match "homepage/:id" => 'products#homepage'
```

and then in the controller you can grab params[:id]

edit:

Maybe change your test to something like:

```
describe 'homepage' do
  it 'should be successful' do
    get 'homepage',:id=>1
    response.should be_success
  end
end
```

Comment: `get "homepage/:id" => 'products#homepage' ` would be safer